# Decimal separator depending on the current Culture

Tags: maui, culture

In my .NET MAUI App, I can switch Culture internally. Depending on that, I wanted to change the decimal separator. In the Entrys I used a routine to only allow the right decimal separator on the TextChanged-Event so that the user just can insert the right Format, I support. This works finde so far:

```cs
public class DecimalSeparatorValidator
{
    private CultureInfo culture;

    public DecimalSeparatorValidator(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        this.culture = culture ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(culture));
    }

    public string ValidateAndReplaceDecimalSeparator(string input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        }

        // Replace the wrong decimal separator
        var numberDecimalSeparator = culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        var correctedInput = input.Replace(numberDecimalSeparator == "." ? "," : ".", numberDecimalSeparator);

        // Validate the input format with regex
        var match = Regex.Match(correctedInput, "^(0|0[.,][0-9]*|[1-9]+[.,]*[0-9]*)$");
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            // If the input does not match the desired format, return null
            return null;
        }

        return correctedInput;
    }
}
```

In XAML, I attached the following StringToDoubleConverter to parse the double:

```xml
Text="{Binding Item.Value, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

```cs
public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Used when the Double Value is converted to the String
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    // Used when the String value from the Entry is converted back to the Double
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            char decimalSeparator = GetDecimalSeparator(stringValue);
            stringValue = stringValue.Replace(decimalSeparator, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator[0]);

            if (double.TryParse(stringValue, out double result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return 0.0; // Default value or handle error accordingly
    }

    private static char GetDecimalSeparator(string input)
    {
        foreach (char character in input)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(character))
            {
                return character;
            }
        }

        return '.';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I switch my Culture internally this is not called anymore and the decimal separators in the View stay the same.

What I wanted to achieve is, that in the corresponding culture where a "." is used as decimal separator this is used when a user types "3.14" and when a "," is used it shows up as "3,14".

Is there a way, I can trigger that, when I change my Culture internally?

Comment: It's a pretty common practice to reload the app when the Culture changes. Couldn't you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to point out one of the TryParse overloads takes in an `IFormatProvider` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-8.0#system-double-tryparse(system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-double@)):

```cs
public static bool TryParse (string? s,
                            IFormatProvider? provider,
                            out double result);
```

You should use this overload and remove your `string.Replace` logic:

```cs
double.TryParse(stringValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out double result)
```

As to your Binding issue, one of the tricks you can use for reacting to culture changes is to use `MultiBinding` and have culture as one of the dependent bindings. This is a dummy in your `MultiBinding` since we're using it as a trigger, we're not using its value:

```xml
<Label.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Item.Value"/>
        <Binding Path="NumberCulture"/>
    <MultiBinding>
</LabelText>
```

That would require you to change the `StringToDoubleConverter` from an `IValueConverter` to an `IMultiValueConverter`, but, you would just take in the first value of the array given and convert as you are currently doing.

As for the second parameter, its a way for you to use the `OnPropertyChanged` system to broadcast to all of the components that are number aware that you've changed `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. e.g.

```cs
public CultureInfo NumberCulture => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

public void ChangeNumberCulture(CultureInfo NewCultureInfo)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = NewCultureInfo;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NumberCulture)); // broadcast to all MultiBindings a change in number culture has occurred.
}
```

I would recommend showing a `Label` all the time, and, having a gesture, say a click to change the visibility to an `Entry` field, so, most of the time, it's only necessary to have a OneWay binding to reflect the number format change.

Comment: Absolutely great - This is working very, very good now! Great trick using a MultiBinding for this with a NumberCulture Property. Thanks a lot for your help on this!!